# PythonでMinecraft統合版のプロキシを作りたい

Tags: python, python3, proxy

統合版マインクラフトのサーバーのプロキシをPythonで自作したいと考えています。
テストのために、ローカル上のプロキシに接続する必要があると考えましたが、UWPのアプリは標準ではlocalhostへのアクセスが制限されているそうなので、まずこちらを実行しました。

```
CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

統合版のプロコトルはUDPのため、まずローカル上のサーバーに既存のPythonで書かれたUDPのプロキシを通して接続しようと考えました。
Minecraftのサーバーをローカル上で19135番に立て(標準のポートはプロキシ用に取っておくため、ポートを変更しました)

Minecraft統合版でlocalhostの19135番に接続しようとしたところ、接続できました。

その後、Gist にあった [udp_proxy.py](https://gist.github.com/ricjcosme/dbb01e6426a1b56aaacf11bbffcc55a3) のプログラムを全て以下のように書き換えて実行しました。

起動ができたことを確認後、Minecraft統合版でlocalhostの19132番へ接続したところ、画像の表示になり、サーバーに接続できませんでした。

(「画像をアップロードできませんでした。サーバーでエラーが発生しました」と表示され、画像のアップロードができなかったため、一時的に文字で表現します
「世界に接続できまでんでした」
というテキストが真ん中より少し上に、中央揃えで表示されており、それに加えて、下部に「ok」と書かれたボタンが存在します)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

__author__      = 'Radoslaw Matusiak'
__copyright__   = 'Copyright (c) 2016 Radoslaw Matusiak'
__license__     = 'MIT'
__version__     = '0.1'


"""
TCP/UDP proxy.
"""

import argparse
import signal
import logging
import select
import socket


FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-10s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger()

LOCAL_DATA_HANDLER = lambda x:x
REMOTE_DATA_HANDLER = lambda x:x

BUFFER_SIZE = 2 ** 10  # 1024. Keep buffer size as power of 2.


def udp_proxy(src, dst):
    """Run UDP proxy.
    
    Arguments:
    src -- Source IP address and port string. I.e.: '127.0.0.1:8000'
    dst -- Destination IP address and port. I.e.: '127.0.0.1:8888'
    """
    LOGGER.debug('Starting UDP proxy...')
    LOGGER.debug('Src: {}'.format(src))
    LOGGER.debug('Dst: {}'.format(dst))
    
    proxy_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    proxy_socket.bind(ip_to_tuple(src))
    
    client_address = None
    server_address = ip_to_tuple(dst)
    
    LOGGER.debug('Looping proxy (press Ctrl-Break to stop)...')
    while True:
        data, address = proxy_socket.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
        
        if client_address == None:
            client_address = address

        if address == client_address:
            data = LOCAL_DATA_HANDLER(data)
            proxy_socket.sendto(data, server_address)
        elif address == server_address:
            data = REMOTE_DATA_HANDLER(data)
            proxy_socket.sendto(data, client_address)
            client_address = None
        else:
            LOGGER.warning('Unknown address: {}'.format(str(address)))
# end-of-function udp_proxy    
    
    
def tcp_proxy(src, dst):
    """Run TCP proxy.
    
    Arguments:
    src -- Source IP address and port string. I.e.: '127.0.0.1:8000'
    dst -- Destination IP address and port. I.e.: '127.0.0.1:8888'
    """
    LOGGER.debug('Starting TCP proxy...')
    LOGGER.debug('Src: {}'.format(src))
    LOGGER.debug('Dst: {}'.format(dst))
    
    sockets = []
    
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(ip_to_tuple(src))
    s.listen(1)

    s_src, _ = s.accept()

    s_dst = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s_dst.connect(ip_to_tuple(dst)) 
    
    sockets.append(s_src)
    sockets.append(s_dst)
    
    while True:
        s_read, _, _ = select.select(sockets, [], [])
        
        for s in s_read:
            data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        
            if s == s_src:
                d = LOCAL_DATA_HANDLER(data)
                s_dst.sendall(d)
            elif s == s_dst:
                d = REMOTE_DATA_HANDLER(data)
                s_src.sendall(d)
# end-of-function tcp_proxy    


def ip_to_tuple(ip):
    """Parse IP string and return (ip, port) tuple.
    
    Arguments:
    ip -- IP address:port string. I.e.: '127.0.0.1:8000'.
    """
    ip, port = ip.split(':')
    return (ip, int(port))
# end-of-function ip_to_tuple


def main():
    """Main method."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='TCP/UPD proxy.')
    
    # TCP UPD groups
    proto_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    proto_group.add_argument('--tcp', action='store_true', help='TCP proxy')
    proto_group.add_argument('--udp', action='store_true', help='UDP proxy')
    
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--src', required=True, help='Source IP and port, i.e.: 127.0.0.1:8000')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--dst', required=True, help='Destination IP and port, i.e.: 127.0.0.1:8888')
    
    output_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    output_group.add_argument('-q', '--quiet', action='store_true', help='Be quiet')
    output_group.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', help='Be loud')
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    if args.quiet:
        LOGGER.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
    if args.verbose:
        LOGGER.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
    
    if args.udp:
        udp_proxy(args.src, args.dst)
    elif args.tcp:
        tcp_proxy(args.src, args.dst)
# end-of-function main    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    local_host = "127.0.0.1"
    local_port = 19132
    target_host = "127.0.0.1"
    target_port = 19135

    udp_proxy(f"{local_host}:{local_port}", f"{target_host}:{target_port}")
```

Comment: 書き換えた部分をピンポイントで書くのではなく、「書き換え後のプログラム全体」を質問中に含めてください。

Comment: どのようにうまくいかなかったのでしょうか？

Comment: 指摘ありがとうございました、修正いたしました